# Need help simplifying this fraction for integration

Tags: indefinite-integrals, fractional-calculus

$$\int \frac{x^6 - 1}{1 + x^2}\ dx\ =\ ?$$

I know that I have to do something like divide the fraction, but I am not getting how, Can someone please help me simplify this?

Comment: Hint : $\frac{x^6-1}{x^2+1}=x^4-x^2+1-\frac{2}{x^2+1}$. The integral of the last term is an arctan-term.

Comment: watch these videos its too basic but long to explain here as an answer.  https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/arithmetic-with-polynomials/long-division-of-polynomials/v/polynomial-division

Comment: ok, I don't really know good math :C

Answer (score 2):

Divide top by bottom:  $$\int \frac{x^6 - 1}{1 + x^2}\ dx=\int \left(x^4-x^2+1-\frac{2}{x^2+1}\right)\,dx$$

$$= \int \left(x^4-x^2 + 1\right)\,dx - 2\int \frac 1{1+x^2}\,dx$$

The first three terms in the sum can be readily integrated using the "power rule".

For the last term, let $x = \tan^{-1}\theta$, and take it from here (inverse tangent).

Comment: what is a power rule?

Comment: @UdayKiran If you don't know the power rule maybe you should be doing some easier integrals..

Comment: I can do easier integrals, my textbook put this integral to be easy :3

Comment: power-rule $$\int x^n\,dx = \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} +c$$ for any $n\neq -1$

Comment: ...so, e.g.,  $\int (x^9)\,dx = \frac {x^{10}}{10} + c$

Comment: I know that formula :/

Answer (score 2):

The first thing we need to do is divide $ \frac{x^6-1}{1+x^2} $.

Doing this gives us

$$
{x^6-1} = (x^4 - x^2 + 1)(1+x^2) - 2
$$
$$
\frac{x^6-1}{1+x^2} = x^4 - x^2 + 1 - \frac{2}{1+x^2}
$$

So, we can now integrate $\frac{x^6-1}{1+x^2}$

$$
\int \frac{x^6-1}{1+x^2} dx = \int (x^4 - x^2 + 1 - \frac{2}{1+x^2}) dx
$$

$$
= \frac{x^5}{5} - \frac{x^3}{3} + x - 2\,arctan(x) + C
$$

Comment: the thing is Im having problem dividing :/

Comment: Khanacademy does a good job explaining polynomial division: watch [this video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra-home/alg-polynomials/alg-long-division-of-polynomials/v/polynomial-division) and the next few videos in the "long division" and "synthetic division" series